# How to get flags in rows of 2 in current scenario?

Tags: css

How can i get flag of rows of 2 using css in following screnario?
Here is [Link](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//premiumvoices.nl/&w=480&h=960&s=1)

Image also attached
[image]

For eg pools flag should be side by side with nederlands.

Comment: What do you expect us to do? Please ***explain*** the problem you're having. Flagged as Very Low Quality.

Comment: @cybermonkey question edited

Comment: It is *still* not good enough. Please ***add your relevant code***, and ***tell us what the problem is***.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't completely get your question but if check if this suits you  http://jsfiddle.net/fvy8ab39/

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/302" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/303" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/304" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/305" />
    </td>
```

Comment: +1 as you were working with a tricky question ***but*** please indent your code.